# My prefabs loading from the resource folder are loading to a weird place in my game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to be able to load my prefabs from my resource folder at 0,0,0 but they are loading automatically at another position and I'm not sure how to change it.

When I instantiated I was able to simply use this line of code.

```
Instantiate(objToSpawn, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
```

However, now I am loading through the file browser utilizing a switch statement and I cant use that same format. Here is my code. Please help if you can. I want to load the prefabs at 0,0,0.

```
GameObject instance;
            switch (objPath)
            {
                case string op when op.Contains("BlueCube"):
                    instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("BlueCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
                    break;
                case string op when op.Contains("RedCube"):
                    instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("RedCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
                    break;
                case string op when op.Contains("GreenCube"):
                    instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("GreenCube", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
                    break;
                case string op when op.Contains("PurpleCube"):
                instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("PurpleCube",  typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your  prefabs are zero centered

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add the rest of your parameters after the Resource.Load like so:

```
instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("BlueCube", typeof(GameObject)), new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

I also recommend to split the Loading and Instantiating like this to avoid confusion:

```
        GameObject instance;
        GameObject prefab = null;

        switch (objPath)
        {
            case string op when op.Contains("BlueCube"):
                prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("BlueCube");
                break;
            case string op when op.Contains("RedCube"):
                prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("RedCube");
                break;
            case string op when op.Contains("GreenCube"):
                prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("GreenCube");
                break;
            case string op when op.Contains("PurpleCube"):
                prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("PurpleCube");
                break;
        }

        if (prefab != null)
        {
            instance = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
```